# Adding dependant objects in import script

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns

We have a console application which imports register records, expected attendees. They arrive in a flat file (exported from a different system), so we wrote some code to import it into the table structure we want, for use in a Register UI.

The data is similar to this:

```
+-----------+----------+------------------+----------+-------------+------------+
| SchoolNum | PersonId |    PersonName    | S_TypeId |   S_Type    |   S_Date   |
+-----------+----------+------------------+----------+-------------+------------+
|       100 |      250 | Tom Cruise       |       20 | Dogfighting | 07/08/2017 |
|       100 |      250 | Tom Cruise       |       15 | Bar singing | 08/08/2017 |
|       100 |      301 | Val Kilmer       |       20 | Dogfighting | 07/08/2017 |
|       100 |      250 | Anthony Edwards  |       15 | Bar singing | 08/08/2017 |
|       100 |       90 | Kelly McGillis   |       35 | Driving     | 09/08/2017 |
|        20 |       40 | Michael Ironside |       20 | Dogfighting | 05/05/1980 |
|        20 |       50 | Tom Skerritt     |       20 | Dogfighting | 05/05/1980 |
|        20 |       50 | Tom Skerritt     |       30 | Leadership  | 04/05/1980 |
+-----------+----------+------------------+----------+-------------+------------+
```

It's going into a SQL Server database, using either Dapper or EF Core, still to be decided on which is more optimal for these inserts.

How can I best structure the code to handle missing dependants? I read about loops and plenty of `if`s, as smelly code, but I'm unsure how to. I also don't particularly like the Add's within the Get's, but am struggling to think of a better way. I know it's violating the SRP.

So the flow is this (`AddTheRows()` being the start point):

```cs
public class RegisterImporter
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    private readonly IEnumerable<ImportedCsvRow> _importedRows;
    private readonly List<ServiceType> _cachedSerivceTypes = new List<ServiceType>();
    private readonly List<Person> _cachedPeople = new List<Person>();
    private readonly List<School> _cachedSchools = new List<School>();

    private readonly IServiceTypeRepository _serviceTypeRepository;
    private readonly IPersonRepository _personRepository;
    private readonly ISchoolRepository _schoolRepository;
    private readonly ISchoolServiceRepository _schoolServiceRepository;

    public RegisterImporter(ILogger logger, IEnumerable<ImportedCsvRow> rows, IServiceTypeRepository serviceTypeRepository, IPersonRepository personRepository, ISchoolRepository schoolRepository, ISchoolServiceRepository schoolServiceRepository)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _importedRows = rows;
        this._serviceTypeRepository = serviceTypeRepository;
        this._personRepository = personRepository;
        this._schoolRepository = schoolRepository;
        this._schoolServiceRepository = schoolServiceRepository;
    }

    public void AddTheRows()
    {
        foreach (ImportedCsvRow csvRow in _importedRows)
        {
            ServiceType serviceType = GetServiceType(csvRow.ServiceType);
            if (serviceType == null) _logger.LogError($"Could not find or add the ServiceType: {csvRow.ServiceType}");

            Person person = GetPerson(csvRow.Person);
            if (person == null) _logger.LogError($"Could not find or add the Person: {csvRow.Person}");

            //Dont attempt to add a school without a schoolType (referrential integrity check).
            School school = GetSchool(csvRow.School);
            if (school == null) _logger.LogError($"Could not find or add the school: {csvRow.School}");

            //Does the service already exist?
            SchoolService service = GetSchoolService(csvRow.ServiceDate, person.Id, school.Id, serviceType.Id);

            if (service == null) _logger.LogError($"Could not find or add the Service");
        }
    }

    private ServiceType GetServiceType(ServiceType serviceType)
    {
        ServiceType serviceTypeToReturn;

        //If the item is already in the cached list then use it rather than hitting the database again.
        ServiceType cachedItem = _cachedSerivceTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == serviceType.Id && x.SubType == serviceType.SubType);
        if (cachedItem != null)
        {
            serviceTypeToReturn = cachedItem;
        }
        else
        {
            serviceTypeToReturn = _serviceTypeRepository.Get(serviceType);
            if (serviceTypeToReturn == null)
            {
                serviceTypeToReturn = _serviceTypeRepository.Add(serviceType);
                if (serviceTypeToReturn != null)
                {
                    //Log it
                    //_logger...... excluded for brevity
                }
            }

            if (serviceTypeToReturn != null &&
                !_cachedSerivceTypes.Any(x => x.Id == serviceTypeToReturn.Id && x.SubType == serviceTypeToReturn.SubType))
                _cachedSerivceTypes.Add(serviceTypeToReturn);
        }

        return serviceTypeToReturn;
    }

    private Person GetPerson(Person Person)
    {
        Person PersonToReturn = null;

        //If the item is already in the cached list then use it rather than hitting the database again.
        var cachedItem = _cachedPeople.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Person.Id);
        if (cachedItem != null)
        {
            PersonToReturn = cachedItem;
        }
        else
        {

            PersonToReturn = _personRepository.Get(Person);
            if (PersonToReturn == null)
            {
                PersonToReturn = _personRepository.Add(Person);
                if (PersonToReturn != null)
                {
                    //Log it
                    //_logger...... excluded for brevity
                }
            }

            if (PersonToReturn != null && _cachedPeople.All(x => x.Id != PersonToReturn.Id))
                _cachedPeople.Add(PersonToReturn);
        }

        return PersonToReturn;
    }

    private School GetSchool(School school)
    {
        School schoolToReturn = null;

        //If the item is already in the cached list then use it rather than hitting the database again.
        var cachedItem = _cachedSchools.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == school.Id);
        if (cachedItem != null)
        {
            schoolToReturn = cachedItem;
        }
        else
        {
            schoolToReturn = _schoolRepository.Get(school);
            if (schoolToReturn == null)
            {
                schoolToReturn = _schoolRepository.Add(school);
                if (schoolToReturn != null)
                {
                    //Log it
                    //_logger...... excluded for brevity
                }
            }

            if (schoolToReturn != null && _cachedSchools.All(x => x.Id != schoolToReturn.Id))
                _cachedSchools.Add(schoolToReturn);
        }

        return schoolToReturn;
    }

    private SchoolService GetSchoolService(DateTime serviceDate, int personId, int schoolId, int serviceTypeId)
    {
        var schoolService = new SchoolService
        {
            ServiceDate = serviceDate,
            ServiceTypeId = serviceTypeId,
            SchoolId = schoolId,
            PersonId = personId
        };

        var serviceToReturn = _schoolServiceRepository.Get(schoolService);
        if (serviceToReturn == null)
        {
            serviceToReturn = _schoolServiceRepository.Add(schoolService);
        }

        return serviceToReturn;
    }
}
public class ImportedCsvRow
{
    public DateTime ServiceDate { get; set; }
    public School School { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; }
}
public class School
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class ServiceType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ServiceSubType SubType { get; set; }
}
public class ServiceSubType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolService
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ServiceDate { get; set; }
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public School School { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public int ServiceTypeId { get; set; }
    public ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; }
    public bool Attended { get; set; }

}

public interface IServiceTypeRepository
{
    ServiceType Get(ServiceType serviceType);
    ServiceType Add(ServiceType serviceType);
}
public interface IPersonRepository
{
    Person Get(Person person);
    Person Add(Person person);
}
public interface ISchoolRepository
{
    School Get(School school);
    School Add(School school);
}

public interface ISchoolServiceRepository
{
    SchoolService Get(SchoolService service);
    SchoolService Add(SchoolService service);
}
```

Comment: There is no `AddTheRows()` method. Did you forget to share your full code?

Comment: @Nikita B No, I hadn't noticed the issue pasting it in.  I can't imagine my question made much sense before, it was missing the whole RegisterImporter class, which I have now added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current API is extremely unclear in my opinion.

> ```
> public interface IServiceTypeRepository 
> {
>     ServiceType Get(ServiceType serviceType);
>     ServiceType Add(ServiceType serviceType); 
> }
> ```

Why do I have to pass `ServiceType` as parameter in order to get it? How does `Add` method returning `ServiceType` makes any sense? What is the relation between parameter  `ServiceType` and returned  `ServiceType`, are those the same instance? You should use clearer method names and signatures to answer those questions.

---

As for `RegisterImporter` implementation - caches should be implemented on repository level. That's one of the main reasons why people bother with repositories in the first place. Whether and how queries are cached is an implementation detail of repository, it is not consumer's responsibility to cache results in simple scenarios.

You can also eliminate copy-pasted code in your `GetX` methods, if you utilize generics, since it boils down to:

```
public static T GetOrAdd<T>(this IRepository<T> repo, T item)
{
    //using your current API
    return repo.Get(item) ?? repo.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: The Add, would be to return the ServiceType with the Id.  The Add, I agree, could probably just use the Id as the parameter.

Comment: @DavidC, yes, that sounds way better. Aren't you confusing `Add` with `Get` though? What you describe sounds like typical `get-something-by-id` method. `Add` should probably be `void`.

Comment: I thought that 'and' or 'or' in a method name indicated a SRP issue.

Comment: @DavidC, sometimes it does, sometimes it does not. `ConcurrentDictionary`comes to mind, it has bunch of those "or"-methods. But it looks fine to me. Do you see SRP violation in above one-line method? I don't. Method name should be accurate. If method "searches existing Person entity and if it is missing adds a new one" then it is perfectly fine to use `GetOrAddPerson` as method name, because it accurately describes what this method does.`GetPerson` does not do that.